# How to register a session for variable and how to use that in another pages for maintain a user with username or password

Tags: php, session

I want to know how to register a session for variable and how to use that in another pages for maintaining a user with username or password .

My code is as follows:

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$role = $_POST['member'];
$sql = "select * from login_register where name = '$name' and password 
= '$password' and role = '$role'";
$retain = mysql_query($sql, $con);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($retain);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count == 1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['name']=$name;
//header("location:admin_home.php");
if ( $role == "admin")
{
header("location:admin_home.php");
}
else  if ( $role == "member")
{
header("location:member_home.php");
}
}
else {
echo  "wrong username and password <a href='index.php'>click here to login   </a>";
}
?>
```

admin_page.php

```
<?php 
// this starts the session 
session_start(); 
// this sets variables in the session 
$_SESSION['name']="name"; 
print "Done"; 
?> 
<html>
Welcome admin
<a href="admin_logout.php"> logout </a>
</html>
```

I dont want to see the user this page without going via login credinals..

Answer (score 0):

Store the session is just like: $_SESSION['username'] = "your username";

And on the next page you check if the session is set with: if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ echo $_SESSION['username'];}

Answer (score 0):

You're correctly setting the session variable in `Login.php`. But then `admin_page.php` overwrites it with:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = "name";
```

Get rid of that assignment, and just use the value that was set by the login page.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    header("Location: Login.php"); // If not set, return to login page
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Hi Barmar...  i tried you codes ., now i cannot see the admin_home.php directly.. but also when i login with the correct username and password also it wont go to the admin_home.php page it returns login.php page only.. pls help me

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` show on the admin page after you login?

Comment: im average in PHP.. i dont know about var_dump($_SESSION) and also dont know to use session in another page

Comment: `var_dump` is a beginner thing, it's how you view the contents of variables when you're debugging a script.

Comment: k... i used var_dump($_session) it shows the following error Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\user_login\admin_home.php on line 2

Comment: It should be `$_SESSION`, not `$_session`. PHP is case sensitive.

Comment: Make sure you have `session_start()` at the very beginning of the script.

Comment: If both scripts are in the same domain and the same folder, session variables should automatically copy from one to the other. I don't know why it's not working for you. Sorry.

Comment: ya all in same folder only .. can u please go throw my login script one time., since i mistaken there to register a session correct .. i wasn't use if(isset()) functions in my login script

Comment: Your login script redirects to `admin_home.php`, but the name of your second script is `admin_page.php`. Are you sure you're working with the right scripts?

Comment: ya im sure my script is working fine with out any session registers . what does my code is do is .. its a login page have 3 fields username, password,and role (member/admin).. all are working and redirect to relevant pages of users ., but the thing is with out login also we can able to view the pages in the browser by putting the urls .. so i thought to use session... that is my first step to know how to register and use it in other pages ..

Comment: You think I don't understand what you're trying to do? It's obvious. All you have to do is use `session_start()` in both scripts and assign to the session variables. I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: k let me check for proper coding thank you very much for the response